# Switching from wired to wireless keyboard causes mouse to wake up PC

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse, wake-up

I had a Logitech wired keyboard and a Logitech M510 wireless mouse connected to my Windows 10 PC (1909 version). In the device manager under "Keyboards", it had the following devices listed: a "HID Keyboard Device" and a "Logitech HID-compliant unifying keyboard". And it had the exact same names for the 2 items under the "Mice and other pointing devices" section, except the word Keyboard was replaced with word Mouse. I can't remember which item under the keyboards section had the "Allow this device to wake computer" option checked in the Power Management tab of the properties window, but only the keyboard was waking up the computer from sleep when any key on it was pressed. The mouse couldn't wake it up, as desired.

Now, after I replaced the wired Logitech keyboard with a Logitech MK320 wireless keyboard, The Logitech M510 mouse is waking up the computer, not the keyboard at all. I tried different combinations of activating the "Allow this device to wake computer" option for both keyboard devices listed while leaving this option disabled for both mouse devices, but the mouse is still waking the PC, not the keyboard. Clicking a button on the mouse or just simply moving it causes my PC to wake up. I want the keyboard only to wake up the PC, not the mouse.  What's the fix for this? Thanks.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that no matter how I configured the devices in the device manager after making the switch with the keyboards, the mouse always woke up the PC, regardless of whether or not the keyboard woke up the PC also at the same time (both devices woke up PC with some configurations). My goal was to have only the keyboard wake up the PC, not the mouse.

Comment: That unit has a unifying receiver, so the result you are getting is completely normal.

Comment: @John What do you mean? I didn't use the unifying receiver that came with the wireless keyboard. I just added the wireless keyboard to the unifying receiver that I was already using for the wireless mouse.

Comment: The mouse will use the unifying receiver you already have. You should be using the new Receiver.

Comment: @John Ok. I'll try using both receivers at the same time.

Comment: As I suggested,use the unifying receiver that came with the new combination. Remove the old receiver, plug in the new receiver and restart the computer

Comment: @John Oh, I see. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Thanks. Receivers can be different and so that may be why the new keyboard is not connecting. A keyboard does not really wake up, they just connect and the new receiver should "unify" all this.

Comment: @John I tried that and had to add mouse to new receiver. Didn't solve problem. Also used both receivers, one for each device. Still no luck. This is what solved the problem. Both receivers are now connected with keyboard to one and mouse to the other. Right now, in device manager, there are 3 devices under the keyboard section and 3 under the mice section. I just enabled "Allow this device to wake computer" for only the first item in keyboards list ("HID Keyboard Device"). Turned it off for all other devices in the keyboard and mice sections. Solved! Keyboard only now waking PC, not the mouse.

Comment: Strange. I have a Logi Tech unit on my desktop.  All 3 (Keyboard, Mouse, Receiver) came in the same box. Installed, restarted and either Keyboard or the Mouse will wake up the computer just fine. Try removing everything except the new two devices.  Restart and test

Comment: @John Did you try having your keyboard only wake the PC and not the mouse? If you try that, I'm sure you'll have the same problem I was having. I think the problem I was having was due to the fact that I had 2 different devices that came from different boxes.

Comment: Yes, keyboard only wakes up the computer.  Mouse only also does this

Comment: No, what I meant was, did you set it up so that only your keyboard wakes up your PC and not the mouse. So that even if you moved the mouse or clicked its buttons, it doesn't wake your PC. If you did, then it is quite strange that my solution worked. Anyways, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I can do it the way you suggest, Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. Wireless mouse was waking up PC even though wake up setting was disabled in the power management.
Also I didn't have shared receiver problem, as I have wired keyboard.

But disabling "Allow this device to wake computer" on one of the device listed **under keyboard** solved the problem. Funny :)
Left the setting on for another device in same listing, to ensure keyboard is able to wake up the PC. You need to do bit of hit and try to check which device you need to change the setting for.